# Why is my powershell script giving an error about a null key not being allowed in a hash literal?

Tags: powershell

I'm new to powershell and trying to create an object based on a class I have made called *User*.  When I try to pass in arguments when I create it, it complains about null values not being allowed in a hash literal, but every argument has a non-null value from what I can tell.  The error is: `A null key is not allowed in a hash literal.`

If I leave off the `-Arguments` parameter and `echo` the object, I get an empty table with no contents, so I think I'm setting up the arguments wrong.

Edit:
I removed the `$` from *FirstName* and *LastName*, but now I'm getting an error that says, `"Cannot find an overload for "User" and the argument count: 1."`

Edit 2:
Below is the working code.

```
class User
{
    [string]$FirstName = ""
    [string]$LastName = ""
    [string]$UserID = ""
}

$testUser = New-Object -TypeName User -Property @{FirstName = "John"; LastName = "Smith"; UserID = "abc123"}
$testUser
```

Below was the incorrect code.

```bsh
class User
{
    [string]$FirstName = ""
    [string]$LastName = ""
    [string]$UserID = ""
}

$testUser = New-Object -TypeName User -Argumentlist @{$FirstName = "John"; $LastName = "Smith"; UserID = "abc123"}
$testUser
```

I'm expecting an object called `$testUser` to be created as well as a table with the values I supplied during its creation.  However, I am receiving the aforementioned error message.  When I either remove or comment out everything after `-TypeName` *User*, the table I was expecting is output, but it's empty as I did not pass it arguments.

Comment: You have `$` in front of the hashtable keys. `@{$FirstName = "John"; $LastName = "Smith"; UserID = "abc123"}` -> `@{FirstName = "John"; LastName = "Smith"; UserID = "abc123"}`

Comment: You were right about the $.  I removed them, and now I'm getting an error that says, "Cannot find an overload for "User" and the argument count: 1."  Do you know what that means?

Comment: Your class doesn't have a constructor that takes a hashtable as it's argument, did you perhaps mean `-Property` instead of `-Argumentlist`?

Comment: Using -Property worked!  Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please post the working code for anyone with a similar issue. I wasn't familiar with this syntax and I'd like to see it :)

Comment: Please consider creating an answer and marking that as the solution if you find that your question was answered correctly.